# Java: Only returns null

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java, and am having trouble with an assignment. For some reason, I'm only getting null. Is there something I did wrong?

```
public class Dieprint
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      Die die1 = new Die();
      die1.roll();
      die1.toString();
      die1.print();
   }
}

class Die
{
   //instance variables
   private int faceValue;
   private int numSides;
   private String faceValue2;

   //constructor
   public Die()
   {
      numSides = 6;
      faceValue = roll();
   }

   //accessors
   public int getValue() { return faceValue; }

   //mutators
   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int)(Math.random()*numSides + 1);
      return faceValue;
   }
   //methods
   public String toString()
   {
     String faceValue2 = ("" + faceValue);
     return faceValue2;
   }

   public String print()
   {
     System.out.println("Result is: " + faceValue2);
     return faceValue2;
   }
}
```

I've tried to make the toString method return faceValue itself, but that didn't work at all.
I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Get rid of the faceValue2 field as it's serves no purpose other than to confuse. Also, why do you have a print method anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `public String toString()` what you did is initiate a new variable faceValue2. Even though you already have that variable in your field, when you wrote `String faceValue2 = {"" + faceValue)` (emphasis on the word **String**) you are now pointing to a another variable called faceValue2, and it is no longer the faceValue2 in your field.

If you walk through your code, the printing is happening in your print method, where there exists a variable called faceValue2. This variable points towards the faceValue2 in your field, which since it has not been changed in your toString() method is still null. Therefore when you print, you get null.

What you can do to solve this problem is simply remove the keyword String, making your code

```
public String toString(){
     faceValue2 = "" + faceValue;
     return faceValue2;
}
```

This will guarantee that you are changing the variable in your field which will in turn change the variable in your print() method, and therefore, change the output you get after running the code.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked great! Plus, I understand where I went wrong now.

Comment: Any time, I'm glad I could help. A small tip though, your print method and string method both return a String representation of your data. They are technically the same method, therefore you have redundant code. If you want to keep your print() method I suggest you make it a void method that includes simply System.out.println(*sample data here*). Good luck further.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Get rid of the faceValue2 variable **and** the `print()` method as they serve no purpose other than to confuse.
- Instead, print out the toString result: `System.out.println(die1);`. This will print out the value returned from Die's toString method.

For example

```
public class DiePrint {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Die die = new Die();
      System.out.println(die);
      die.roll();
      System.out.println(die);
   }
}

class Die {
   private static final int DEFAULT_NUM_SIDES = 6;
   private int faceValue;
   private int numSides;

   // default constructor
   public Die() {
      this(DEFAULT_NUM_SIDES);
   }

   // if numSides can vary, then have a constructor that will
   // allow one to set it.
   public Die(int numSides) {
      this.numSides = numSides;
      roll(); // no need to set numSides when rolling. it's already done
   }

   // accessors should reflect the field name
   public int getFaceValue() {
      return faceValue;
   }

   public int getNumSides() {
      return numSides;
   }

   // mutators
   public int roll() {
      faceValue = (int) (Math.random() * numSides + 1);
      return faceValue;
   }

   // methods
   public String toString() {
      String faceValue2 = ("" + faceValue);
      return faceValue2;
   }

}
```